# Was Broly able to transform into Super Saiyan 4 in Dragon Ball Z?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-gt

Broly is shown to have a tail as a baby.

[image: Broly as a baby]

But the tail is not there when he is an adult or kid, which means that he has the potential to become Super Saiyan 4. The only time he has a tail is when he was cloned, as shown in *Bio-Broly*.
The time span in which Broly does not have a tail is: *Broly — The Legendary Super Saiyan* and *Broly — Second Coming*.

Do we know if Broly was able to transform into Super Saiyan 4 in *Dragon Ball Z*?

The only time he turned to Super Saiyan 4 is in *Dragon Ball Heroes*, which is a game and not canon.

Comment: Please rewrite your question in proper English. We don't understand what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Even if you have trouble with English itself, at least try to make the question clearer, and someone can review the wording later. As it is, we cannot understand what you are asking and cannot help you.

Comment: I'm bad at grammar so plz don't hate me

Comment: So your going to deal with my crappy grammar 

Comment: Could you at least try to separate clauses in your sentence? It seems like you have 3 or 4 sentences crammed into that single sentence that now composes the body of your question. As for the title, do mean to ask if Broly *can* transform into a SS4? I can help with rewording and grammar, but I need to know what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Fine i will try

Comment: This is what I have for now but do you want me to keep editing becuse i really don't want to.

Comment: I have edited your question. Is this what you wanted to ask? If so, let me know so we can reopen the question. Also, I didn't "want you to keep editing", I was just trying to help *you* get *your* question reopened. If you "really don't want to" keep editing *your own question, don't expect other users to do it for you*. Take this into consideration next time you want to ask a question.

Comment: Well I'm ok with it

Comment: No for all the reasons in the answers as well as the fact you must be able to control super saiyan oozaru mode to become ssj4, which I think would be impossible for Broly because he is insane, and wouldn't have a strong enough mind to conquer it.

Answer (score 3):

Broly wasn't a canon character and Super Saiyan 4 isn't a canon transformation, so the idea of Broly being a canon Super Saiyan 4 is kind of madness.

Broly is a character from the movies, in which there is no hint that he or anyone else can become a Super Saiyan 4, and SS4 is from GT and there was no mention of Broly in GT. If he went SS4 in some game, then in the canon of that game he is able to, but otherwise I would say no, there is no reason to think Broly could be a SS4, as even his normal Super Saiyan form is in fact pretty weird and not particularly similar to the main characters' Super Saiyan transformations.

Answer (score 0):

No, Super Saiyan 4 was never a canon - all of the Dragon Ball GT episodes are filler and Akira Toriyama, the manga author, had never made SSJ4 and the next official transformation or rather power up is "Super Saiyan God"  - achievable by 5? (I don't remember) Saiyan powering up one Saiyan.

Comment: But broly was super saiyan 4 in dragon ball heros game in a cut scene And that's not cannon becuse its a game

Comment: Iirc Broly wasn't canon either.

Answer (score 0):

No Broly was not able to transform into Super Saiyan 4 in Dragon Ball Z.
Actually no character was able to achieve Super Saiyan 4 in Dragon Ball Z as Super Saiyan 4 was introduced in Dragon Ball GT.

I will not go into details of what is canon and what is filler as the other answers have explained it well.

However, Broly had a Legendary Super Saiyan form - the only Super Saiyan transformation that Goku has not been able to achieve in the series, canon or otherwise.
How strong the Legendary form is in comparison to Super Saiyan, Super Saiyan 2 etc. is open to interpretation. Still one can say quite surely say that Legendary Super Saiyan form was considerably weaker than Super Saiyan 4.

So, no Broly never achieved Super Saiyan 4 and he never got as strong as Super Saiyan 4 either.

Answer (score 0):

No because there is no Super Saiyan 4 it is not canon to DBZ however in DBGT Vegeta turned into SSJ4 with the help of a machine build by his wife Bulma so possible that he can since his a saiyan only based on a series GT not DBZ.